# Getting two double substrings from a string starting after a particular substring

Tags: java, formatting

For an Android application, an API I'm using returns the following format response :

```
"2016-05-08T14:07:58.738Z" | Lat: 50.012122| Long: 50.012122| Precision: 22.44868"
```

I'm tring to extract the double after "Lat: " and the one after "Long: " in two Double using different versions of .substring. The code becomes quickly long because I make multiple calls to substring (to get the values after Lat and Long, and also to remove the | after and everything else).

I'm searching for a more succinct and noncomplex methot that I can't see at the moment.

Thank you.

Comment: split on `|`, take the middle two results, split on whitespace, take the second entry and parse it into a `Double`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the suggestions of @luk2302, I did this :

```
String lat = string.split("\\|")[1].split("\\s+")[2];
String long = string.split("\\|")[2].split("\\s+")[2];
```

And finally Double.parseDouble to transform to Double after.